# 125vdc Snubber Circuit for Relay Contacts - 125vdc, 3.2amp load

Tags: relay, snubber, contact

Does anyone know of a manufacturer that makes a prebuilt "ready-to-go" Off-the-shelf snubber circuit / Arc Suppressor that can be used to protect the contacts of my dinrail-mounted relay.  My load current that the relay is switching is 125vdc, 3.2amps.

The Snubber/Arc Suppressor would need to quench the arc that occurs when the contacts open up.

So far, I've only been able to locate a company in Colorado called Blue Point Engineering and from what I can tell, their unit is only suitable for AC circuits.

Please point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Oh, I want that so bad!!!!! I have a 75VDC generator of enormous inductance I need to be able to interrupt.

Answer (score 0):

I would look on phoenix contact, they have all kinds of surge arrestors and installation protection equipment